# Can you identify this broker/trading platform by looking at this picture?

Tags: software, broker, online-brokerage, online-trading

Can someone identify what broker or trading platform this is?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like [**E*TRADE Pro**](https://us.etrade.com/active-trading). i.e. See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAeQ4.jpg).  (It's promotional and I'd rather not show it inline.)

In that image, the chart window you've displayed as floating appears to be docked and surrounded by more stuff. I imagine these trading platforms are highly configurable because the kind of information traders want to see is a preference based on chosen trading style.

See also [here](http://www.onlinebrokerrev.com/etrade/power-etrade-pro-charts.php) for [another screen shot](http://www.onlinebrokerrev.com/etrade/power%20etrade%20pro01.jpg) from a site I found (via Google) that reviews trading platforms. This second screen shot is more detailed and an easier match up to what you posted.  The E*Trade logo is clearly visible at top-left.